# Flexbox inside CSS grid layout with dynamic content

Tags: css, vuejs2, flexbox, css-grid, vuetify.js

I have a grid layout with the cells having dynamic heights (revealing info on mouseover). I want the grid to expand the row height based on the size of the content and shrink it again after hover is over. There can be multiple items in each cell and the items should always fill the cell completely

- The template-row-height of the grid is set to auto
- The container inside the cell uses flexbox to maximize the content

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/thexperiments/pen/VRZNeW)

```
.grid {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: 150px 150px 150px 150px;
   grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;
   margin: 20px;
}
```

The problem looks different across browsers but it always has the same kind of symptoms.

- after the hover the row height will not shrink again
- after changing some style of the cell (for example in chrome dev-tools) the layout is fixed. (Re-layout happening)
- under some circumstances the items/rows will grow further with each hover

Looks like it is working as intended with at least Chrome 72 and Firefox 65.0.1, so Safari is the last one, but very important for mobile**

## What I already tried

- All force-reflow tricks (JS + CSS) I could find as I was guessing that only reflow was not triggering
- Removing/adding various styles to/from the children to see if one of them forces the children to stay that size after resize
- removing/adding elements to/from the cell to see how the affect the behavior

At first it caused the most problems with Safari and I thought it might be

> Safari does not yet support intrinsic and extrinsic sizing with grid properties such as grid-template-rows
>   ( https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid )

However these problems should not be there in Chrome and also the expansion works OK in Safari if the content of the cell doesn't have 100% height

My current guess is that it could just be browser bugs in the relatively recent grid support. Thus I would also appreciate workaround suggestions.

Behavior in Safari(wrong):

[image: Behavior in Safari (wrong)]

Behavior in Chrome (correct):

[image: Behavior in Chrome (correct)]

Comment: Hi, please include a [mcve] of the problem *in the question itself*. Just linking to a CodePen is not sufficient. Otherwise your question risks being closed.

Comment: This is the smallest example I could reproduce the error with

Comment: I think you misunderstand... with the code you have in the question, you can't reproduce anything. In case it's still not clear... the only code you have in the question is one CSS selector and four properties. We need to see enough HTML, CSS, and JS to reproduce the issue. The site has a live code snippet feature in the post editor; it's a far cry from a site like CodePen, but you can at least link to CDNs for external libraries like Vue.